# What is the best way to use the same redis connection as sideqik?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I want to be able to use and connect to the same redis instance as the one that is defined for sidekiq.

In resque, it is retrieved by`Resque.redis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq takes a block, and the equivalent method is:

`Sidekiq.redis { |x| x.redis }`